# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException'

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors, xcode4.5

I keep getting this error when running my application in Xcode 4.5.:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
>   this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Garage.'
>   *** First throw call stack:

Does it mean that there is something declared as Garage in my ArmyViewController?

Thanks in advance for those who answer.

Comment: Verify that you don't have any old IBOutlet connections in interface builder.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. You have not given enough info for anything other than general help. If you look at the `Related` section you will see that there are various questions that may have solutions to your problem but there's no way to narrow it down without more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble finding where the exception is being thrown then do the following:

From the Breakpoint Navigator (7th icon) you will notice down towards the bottom of your Xcode IDE 3 little icons (plus, minus, and checkbox) along with a search field.  Click on the "+" plus icon, which will display a small popup menu .... choose "Add Exception Breakpoint."

Now, re-run your application again and notice where the code stops ... your exception is coming from there (i.e., the callstack).

Comment: I just get this when doing what you told me and the bottom window (IS is the debugger?) Only has lldb in it                                                                     #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}